# How can I automatically fold a file when start and end markers are the same?

Tags: vim

I have a plain text file that uses `-- >8 --` as section separators, e.g.:

```
-- >8 --

first section
some content
more content

-- >8 --

second section
some content
more content

-- >8 --
```

In order to more easily navigate the file, I want to fold sections between markers. I was expecting that would be as easy as:

```
set foldmethod=marker
set foldmarker=--\ >8\ --,--\ >8\ --
```

But it results in nested folds.

I have found that I can use a fold-expression to achieve this (see answer below), but it seems rather excessive. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that I can use a fold-expression to do this:

```
set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=(getline(v:lnum)=='--\ >8\ --')?1:2
```

Screenshot:

```
- -- >8 --
|++---  5 lines: first section------------------------------------------------
| -- >8 --
|++---  5 lines: second section-----------------------------------------------
| -- >8 --
```

Comment: That's how I would do it, too. Doesn't look _excessive_ to me.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: I guess you're right, I was just hooked up on the idea of having fold-marker do this. Thanks.